# How to filter a dictionary by two string parameters?

Tags: python, filter, parameters

I currently have a script which filters a dictionary by one parameter (it looks the following):

```
# loop over first  dict, get keys + values
for k1, v1 in hostname_list['sap_landscape'].items():
    # loop over second dictionary, get keys + values
    for k2, v2 in v1.items():
        if k2 == "hostname" and v2 == name:
            print(v1)
```

The console input looks like the following:

```
python3 example.py --name=dceu3005 # (I'm using click options for the input parameter)
```

And the output looks something like this:

```
{'hostname': 'dceu3005', 'SDI': 'G', 'Type': 'Optimal', 'Landscape': 'Opti', 
 'Severity': 'GTO', 'Username': None, 'UserID': None, 'Global': None, 'Cycle': 2}
```

The problem I'm facing now is, that I need to have a second parameter meaning the dictionary has to be filtered by either one parameter (example: name or severity) but also has to able to be filtered by two parameters at the same time (example: name AND severity) so if I have a input like this:

```
python3 example.py --name=dceu3005 --severity=PRD
```

It should filter by both criteria and output only the servers name that also has the specified severity.

I have tried to solve the problem by assigning the key and the value to a variable each and then creating a method with a `if` statement looking like this:

```
hostname = v1.get("hostname")
obj_severity = v1.get("Severity")

def name_and_severity(k2, v2, severity):
    if k2 == "Severity" and v2 == severity:
        return True

def name(hostname, name, severity):
    if not severity and hostname == name:
        return True
    
def severity(severity, obj_severity):
    if not name and severity == obj_severity:
        return True
```

But this doesn't seem to work or am I doing something wrong?

If you have the time please explain to me why you did what you did so I can learn from my mistakes/learn something new.

Comment: Can you please provide `hostname_list`.

Comment: @ChrisOram i can provide you a few lines but the whole file is about but 800 lines long. the way its constructed always repeats. it looks like this
{"sap_landscape": {"dce1500": {"hostname": "dce1500", "SID": "ST", "Type": "Spo", "Landscape": "SBX", "Severity": "FDS", "Username": null, "UserID": 159343, "Global": null, "Cycle": 1}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `<dict_name>.get(<key_name>)` method to get the value of specific key and match it with your defined value:

```
for v1 in hostname_list['sap_landscape'].values():
    if all([v1.get("hostname", None) == name,
            v1.get("Severity", None) == severity
        ]):
        print(v1)
```

`None` will be returned if there is no key named `hostname` or `Severity`.